# When does a semigroup homomorphism preserve identities on monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-languages, semigroups, monoid, semigroup-homomorphism

Let $X,Y$ be [monoids](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Monoid), with identities $e_X,e_Y$, respectively. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a **semigroup homomorphism**. That is, any function which satisfies
$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)\quad\forall x,y \in X\tag{1}$$

I know that $f$ is *not* necessarily a **monoid homomorphism**, where the definition of a monoid homomorphism is the same as a semigroup homomorphism, but with the additional requirement that it preserve identities:
$$f(e_X)=e_Y\tag{2}$$
This second property is required [see, e.g., the discussion in a number of other math.SE threads, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872916/if-g-h-are-monoids-and-not-groups-prove-that-fe-g-e-h-may-be-wrong) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626597/do-monoid-homomorphisms-preserve-the-identity?) for examples where $(1)$ holds but $(2)$ does not.]

The reason I'm interested: In formal language theory, one deals with *the set of all finite strings over some alphabet*, which forms a monoid under concatenation, with the empty string being the identity (the "free monoid"). In this area, it is common to state that the identity-preserving property $(2)$ can be derived from the semigroup homomorphism property $(1)$ (see for example [Kozen 1997, Lecture 10](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-1-4612-1844-9), or [Kurz's lecture notes, Lecture 7](http://cmsc-28000.cs.uchicago.edu/2018-spring/Lectures/07/)).  I know this must be due to something about the structure of this kind of monoid, since it isn't true in general.

My question is: what must be true about monoids $X$ and $Y$ such that all semigroup homomorphisms mapping $X$ to $Y$ preserve the identity (and as such are monoid homomorphisms)?

Comment: All you need to know is that semigroup homomorphisms preserve idempotents and that, if $e$ is an idempotent of $Y$, then the constant map  to $e$ is a semigroup homomorphism.

Comment: okay, but iiuc, the answer to my question is that for fixed monoids $X$, $Y$, all semigroup homomorphisms are monoid homomorphisms iff the following property holds: "$e\in Y$ is idempotent $\implies e=e_Y$". (as stated in @ckefa's answer)  Is that somehow equivalent to what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, it was kind of a hint to answer your question. The details are contained in @ckefa's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We claim that all semigroup homomorphisms mapping $X$ to $Y$ preserve the identity if and only if $Y$ has exactly one element satisfying $y^{2} = y$ (which has to be $e_{Y}$).

Suppose $Y$ has only one solution to $y^{2} = y$ (which has to be $e_{Y}$). Note that $f(e_{X})f(e_{X}) = f(e_{X}e_{X}) = f(e_{X})$, so we must have $f(e_{X}) = e_{Y}$. This proves one direction.

For the other direction, suppose $Y$ contains an element $y$ such that $y^{2} = y$ but $y \neq e_{Y}$. Then $f \colon X \to Y$ sending all of $X$ to $y$ is a semigroup homomorphism, because for all $x
_{1}, x_{2} \in X$ we have $f(x_{1})f(x_{2}) = y^{2} = y = f(x_{1}x_{2})$. This semigroup homomorphism $f$ does not send $e_{X}$ to $e_{Y}$. This proves the other direction.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thank you! My intuition was that it would require $Y$ to not have another element that was identity-like, but I couldn’t see how to go about making that intuition precise.

Comment: So, to be clear, in formal language theory, where the monoids of interest are the free monoids, (1) implies (2) since the empty string $\varepsilon$ is always the only idempotent element.

Comment: @postylem Yes, exactly!

Comment: It's interesting because in the formal language theory sources the proofs given for the lemma that (1) implies (2) usually use the concept of _length_ of the string, and the fact that the only string of length zero is $\varepsilon$ [for example the Kozen lecture I linked gives the proof as $|f(\varepsilon)|=|f(\varepsilon\varepsilon)|=|f(\varepsilon)f(\varepsilon)|=|f(\varepsilon)|+|f(\varepsilon)| \implies |f(\varepsilon)|=0 \implies f(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon$].  This is a nice way of showing it, but it's interesting that it's not necessary to have the length property in general.